# Check for string in URL

Tags: 7, uri

How can I check for a specific directory in my URL? I need to display an image if I'm in http://www.mywebsite.com/displayimg/mypage but not if I'm in http://www.mywebsite.com/mypage... would it be something involving drupal_get_path?

Comment: What you exactly want to do ? please explain in a better way

Comment: what are 'displayimag' and 'mypage'? are they strings or ids? what?

Comment: displayimg is a directory in my website. If the page points to it, I need to find a way to get the info from the URL and instruct Drupal to display a particular img on my page (mypage).

Comment: Ok, you can do it by checking `arg` from the URL. see [arg](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [arg](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) to check for URL arguments. In your case, the second argument has to be empty, so you can try something like this:

```
if (arg(0) == 'displayimg' && arg(1) == 'mypage') {
  // Do something meaningful.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to use block to display image. Use block visibility setting for displaying on specific URL.